# AWS lambda add PATH variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to append the root path of the ZIP file for Amazon Lambda function because I have placed an executable file there.

I have tried: `PATH = "$PATH:$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT:/"`

It did not work.

Comment: Where do you need to append path variable? Is that in API gateway or Lambda environment variables?

Comment: How about instead of trying to modify the run-time environment variables, just explicitly specify the full path to the executable when you run it?

Comment: What runtime are you using? Also, how are you referencing (in code) the `PATH` variable you're setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the lambda console itself by modifying the environment variables.

[image: environment-variables]