# Append a directory to Amazon Lambda Environment Variables $NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Default Env Variable as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables):

```
NODE_PATH:/opt/nodejs/node8/node_modules/:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR/node_modules
```

I want to append my custom directory to it (NOT to override all)

```
NODE_PATH:$NODE_PATH:/opt/nodejs/mycustom-directory
```

I tried the above from lambda console it overrides all. `$NODE_PATH` is added as a string. It is not parsing `$NODE_PATH`

Output I got when printing env:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/opt/nodejs/mycustom-directory
```

Similar Question but no Solution still: [AWS lambda add PATH variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136472/aws-lambda-add-path-variable)

Answer (score 3):

I needed this too, as I am using AWS Lambda Layers, which are placed on the default `NODE_PATH`, and wanted to also be able to use local roots to avoid long relative paths (such as `import bar from foo/bar` instead of `import bar from ../../../../foo/bar`, but I didn't find any way to *append* to `NODE_PATH` without losing the default ones - as soon as it's set, the paths to `node_modules` - including the `aws-sdk` module, are lost.

The only solutions I can think of are:

1. Explicitly set `NODE_PATH` to the default value plus your custom one (which adds an ugly dependency to lambda internal environment configuration which you shouldn't have to care about)
2. Put your custom library in a layer. Many times this is a good solution if you can extract sub-modules as separate layers (but it doesn't help for situations like elimination of long relative paths within the application itself like I described above).
3. Append programatically, by having the *very first lines* of your application do

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = process.env.NODE_PATH + ":my-custom-path";
require("module").Module._initPaths(); // This re-initalizes the module loader to use the new NODE_PATH.

require('some-custom-module-in-my-custom-path'); // should work
require('aws-sdk') // should also work
```

This may not be the prettiest hack, but it should do the trick (disclaimer: haven't actually tried this in a AWS Lambda environment but it works locally using Node 12 at least).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same problem.
I wrote a code to check if the lambda function applies the shell variable expansions, and to figure out they don't.

I set environment variable `FOO` as `$NODE_PATH`,

Then, run the check code (in lambda function):

```
const { FOO } = process.env;
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(FOO);
};
```

The output is:

```
2019-02-22T08:29:05.714Z    cde21239-628f-4a79-b046-6a14f177f59e    $NODE_PATH
```

I just rewrite the whole `NODE_PATH` to be `(my custom library path):/opt/nodejs/lib:/opt/nodejs/node8/node_modules/:/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/var/runtime/node_modules`

the default value of `NODE_PATH` is explained there:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Comment: I have tried this too, executing shell commands from nodejs code, `echo env` showed it took as a string `$NODE_PATH`. Is there is any way without overriding the existing and just append to it ?