# How to modify an existing environment variable in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to be able to supplement an existing environment variable (specifically NODE_PATH) in an AWS Lambda function created with the NodeJsFunction construct.

Whilst I can add new environment variables, I don't seem to be able to see a way to extend one of the defaults.  The documentation is confusing because it suggests a $VAR style but its not actually a substitution pattern, merely a way in the docs to refer that one var might contain the contents of another var.

In my NodeJsFunction props, I want to be able to specify:

```
environment: {
  NODE_PATH: "$NODE_PATH:/opt/special"
}
```

Where the default node path is inserted ahead of the special path. e.g. `/opt/nodejs/node_modules:/opt/special`.

I also tried `${NODE_PATH}:...` but that doesn't make a difference.

While the AWS docs does indicate what the value of NODE_PATH is likely to be, ideally I don't want hardcode this, as that seems likely to break in the future if they change the layout of the lambda filesystem, node version or other aspect of the Lambda runtime.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624226/append-a-directory-to-amazon-lambda-environment-variables-node-path